# How to fix gradle build failed due to void org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.LazyPublishArtifact.<init>(org.gradle.api.provider.Provider) error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am getting following exception when I try to build the spring boot project using Gradle build command. The code comiples and runs fine in IntelliJ Idea.

```
PS C:\SVN\Dactyl\IIOTWizards\SCADA\Trunk\source\Services\universal-service> gradle build                                                                                                

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
'void org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.LazyPublishArtifact.<init>(org.gradle.api.provider.Provider)'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 657ms
```

This is my build.gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.iiot.wizards'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
//sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation files('lib/connection-manager-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/dlms-lib-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/emdb-entities-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/emdb-model-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/emflex-ansi-meter-reader-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/emflex-dlms-meter-reader-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-common-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-communication-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-dnp3-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-dnp3-meter-reader-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-history-data-provider-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-history-data-writers-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-licensing-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-local-data-cache-manager-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-log-manager-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-messaging-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-mio-meter-reader-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-modbus-gprs-read-meter-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-modbus-meter-reader-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-scheduler-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/modbus-master-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/TinyLog-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/Utils-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/jniwrap-3.12.jar')
    implementation files('lib/GoogleProtocolBuffer_2.6.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/comm.jar')
    implementation files('lib/RXTXcomm.jar')
    implementation files('lib/iiot-wizards-history-entities-2.0.0.1.jar')

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.11.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.12.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3
    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.paho', name: 'org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3', version: '1.2.5'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client
    implementation group: 'com.rabbitmq', name: 'amqp-client', version: '5.13.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-compress', version: '1.21'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils
    implementation group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: '1.9.4'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-cli/commons-cli
    implementation group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.4'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.4'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging
    implementation group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math3', version: '3.6.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.9'

//    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/gnu.io/rxtx
//    implementation group: 'gnu.io', name: 'rxtx', version: '2.1.7'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.5.7.Final'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apiguardian/apiguardian-api
    implementation group: 'org.apiguardian', name: 'apiguardian-api', version: '1.1.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.dom4j/dom4j
    implementation group: 'org.dom4j', name: 'dom4j', version: '2.1.3'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.fastinfoset/FastInfoset
    implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.fastinfoset', name: 'FastInfoset', version: '2.0.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core
    testImplementation group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-core', version: '2.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: '1.0.2.Final'

//    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.ogm/hibernate-ogm-mongodb
//    implementation group: 'org.hibernate.ogm', name: 'hibernate-ogm-mongodb', version: '5.4.1.Final'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.istack/istack-commons-runtime
    implementation group: 'com.sun.istack', name: 'istack-commons-runtime', version: '4.1.0-M1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist
    implementation 'org.javassist:javassist:3.28.0-GA'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-core
    implementation 'io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:4.2.4'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.narayana.jta/narayana-jta
    testImplementation 'org.jboss.narayana.jta:narayana-jta:5.12.1.Final'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all
    implementation 'io.netty:netty-all:4.1.67.Final'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client
    implementation 'com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:5.13.1'

//    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core
//    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.14.1'
//
//    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl
//    testImplementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.14.1'
//
//    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api
//    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.14.1'

//    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api
//    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32'

//    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12
//    testImplementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.32'

//    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple
//    testImplementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.32'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc
    implementation 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.36.0.3'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.staxex/stax-ex
    implementation 'org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:2.1.0-M1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/txw2
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:3.0.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple
    implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'


    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc:2.5.6'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.6'
//    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.5.4'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.5.6'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:2.5.6'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.5.6'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.6'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200'
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    runtimeOnly 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:21.1.0.0'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.28'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.5.6'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:5.5.1'

}

//jar {
//    manifest {
//        attributes(
//                'Class-Path': 'comm.jar jdom.jar optra.jar jxl-2.6.jar RXTXcomm.jar javax.ejb.jar javax.jms.jar sqljdbc42.jar guava-16.0.jar hamcrest-core.jar javax.servlet.jar commons-io-2.7.jar javax.resource.jar commons-cli-1.4.jar log4j-api-2.9.0.jar rabbitmq-client.jar javax.annotation.jar log4j-core-2.9.0.jar portmapper-2.0.0.jar javax.servlet.jsp.jar javax.transaction.jar netty-3.9.0.Final.jar sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar metrics-core-2.2.0.jar metrics-core-3.1.2.jar poi-3.10.1-20140818.jar javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar poi-ooxml-3.10.1-20140818.jar GoogleProtocolBuffer_2.6.1.jar poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1-20140818.jar hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar apiguardian-api-1.0.0.jar opentest4j-1.1.1.jar byte-buddy-1.10.7.jar hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar classmate-1.5.1.jar antlr-2.7.7.jar dom4j-2.1.1.jar hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar jandex-2.1.1.Final.jar javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar stax-ex-1.8.jar txw2-2.3.1.jar commons-compress-1.19.jar javax.jms.jar javax.annotation.jar javax.ejb.jar javax.transaction.jar javax.resource.jar javax.servlet.jar javax.servlet.jsp.jar javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar comm.jar jdom.jar optra.jar lombok.jar ojdbc7.jar jxl-2.6.jar comm-2.0.jar RXTXcomm.jar javax.ejb.jar javax.jms.jar seroUtils.jar sqljdbc42.jar guava-16.0.jar h2-1.4.200.jar junit-4.10.jar txw2-2.3.1.jar antlr-2.7.7.jar dom4j-2.1.1.jar stax-ex-1.8.jar jniwrap-3.12.jar hamcrest-core.jar javax.servlet.jar commons-io-2.7.jar javax.resource.jar jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar classmate-1.5.1.jar commons-cli-1.4.jar log4j-api-2.9.0.jar rabbitmq-client.jar javax.annotation.jar log4j-core-2.9.0.jar opentest4j-1.1.1.jar portmapper-2.0.0.jar slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar byte-buddy-1.10.2.jar byte-buddy-1.10.7.jar javax.servlet.jsp.jar javax.transaction.jar json-simple-1.1.1.jar netty-3.9.0.Final.jar sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar commons-lang3-3.11.jar FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar jandex-2.1.1.Final.jar jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar metrics-core-2.2.0.jar metrics-core-3.1.2.jar jackson-core-2.11.1.jar javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar junit-jupiter-5.4.2.jar poi-3.10.1-20140818.jar sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.1.jar apiguardian-api-1.0.0.jar commons-compress-1.19.jar javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar jackson-databind-2.11.1.jar junit-jupiter-api-5.4.2.jar javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar poi-ooxml-3.10.1-20140818.jar GoogleProtocolBuffer_2.6.1.jar jackson-annotations-2.11.1.jar javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar junit-jupiter-engine-5.4.2.jar junit-jupiter-params-5.4.2.jar hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar junit-platform-engine-1.4.2.jar mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar junit-platform-commons-1.4.2.jar hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1-20140818.jar org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.1.jar hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar'
//        )
//    }
//}
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Did you try one of additional gradle arguments suggested in the error message to get more details about the error?

Comment: @aled I did, nothing useful. Too big to put here.

Comment: It may be useful to answer to have more details. Try extracting details of the error only, not the full thing. If you don't provide more information it is very unlikely anyone can help you.

Comment: Looks like a failure due to a `NoSuchMethodError`. What version of Gradle are you using? Also, `--stacktrace` should identify the code that's calling the method that doesn't exist.

Comment: @aled Added link to full debug log.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Added link to full debug log. I didn't find NoSuchMethodError here. Using Gradle 8.1.1

Comment: @Ram You may want to delete that debug log as it can contain sensitive information

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are using Spring Boot 2.6 [which does not support Gradle 8.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.x/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#introduction):

> Spring Boot’s Gradle plugin requires Gradle 6.8, 6.9, or 7.x and can be used with Gradle’s configuration cache.

Support for Gradle 8 was added in Spring Boot 2.7 so you can either upgrade to Spring Boot 2.7 or downgrade to Gradle 7.x.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing this from intelliJ and returning fine otherwise or vice-versa, you may need to verify you are using local gradle installation in your build tool setting. This will give consistent result.

To verify this, follow:
File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle

Where, at the bottom you might select both JVM and distribution for gradle

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen this happen when `id 'java'` was not the first item in the `plugins` section.  For me, changing

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
```

to

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}
```

fixed the `LazyPublishArtifact` error.  I'm not sure exactly what is going on there, but the second snippet is what Spring Initializer produces as of early 2024.